# Write a regular expression to parse following string

Tags: regex, sed

I am using `sed` command and I want to parse following string:

```
Mr. XYZ                              Mr. ABC, PQR
Ward-2, abc                   vs.    MG Road, Pune,
                                     Pune Dist.,

(Appellant)                          (Respondent)
```

Now I want to parse the above string and I want to  get Appellant part separated from above example and respondent part separated.

That is I want following output:

`Mr. XYZ Ward-2, abc(Appellant)`  that is one output and `Mr. ABC, PQR MG Road, Pune, Pune Dist.,(Respondent)` is another output by using `sed` command.

I used following regex but not getting proper output:

```
sed -n '/assessment year/I{ :loop; n; /Respondent/Iq; p; b loop}' abc.txt
```

Comment: How can you tell which part is the appelant? On the second line you can match `vs.`, but what do you use on the other lines?

Comment: @Barmar Before the above text start in Text document one line is present i.e. Assessment Year 2002-03, 2007-08 & 2008-09 then above text will start to next line

Comment: I mean how can the regexp tell which part of each line is the appellant and which is the respondent? If you can't explain it, you can't write a regexp to parse it.

Comment: Have you tried writing anything yourself? We can't help you fix your regexp if you don't post what you tried, and we're not here to do it for you.

Comment: @Barmar I used `sed -n '/assessment year/I{ :loop; n; /Respondent/Iq; p; b loop}' abc.txt`

Comment: Put it in the question.

Comment: Why is your regexp looking for `/assessment year/` when that is not present in your input? Edit your question so the input, output, attempt, and description of requirements all make sense wrt each other.

Answer (score 0):

sed is always the wrong tool for any job that involves looking at multiple lines. Just use awk, it's what it was invented for. Here's GNU awk for a couple of extensions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS="30 7 99" }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        gsub(/^\s*|\s*$/,"",$i)
        if ($i != "") {
            rec[i] = (rec[i]=="" ? "" : rec[i] " ") $i
        }
    }
}
/^\(/ {
    print rec[1]
    print rec[3]
    delete rec
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Mr. XYZ Ward-2, abc (Appellant)
Mr. ABC, PQR MG Road, Pune, Pune Dist., (Respondent)
```

Answer (score -1):

I achieved this with following way by using ruby:

```
appellant_respondent = %x(sed -n '/assessment year/I{ :loop; n; /respondent/Iq; p; b loop}' #{@file_name}).split("\n")
appellant_name_array = []
respondent_name_array = []
appellant_respondent.delete("")
appellant_respondent.each do |names|
   names_array = names.split(/\s+\s+/)
   appellant_name_array << names_array.first if names_array.first != ""
   respondent_name_array << names_array.last if names_array.last != ""
end
@item[:appellant] = appellant_name_array.join(' ').gsub(/\s+vs\.*\s+/i, ' ').strip
@item[:respondent] = respondent_name_array.join(' ').gsub(/\s+vs\.*\s+/i, ' ').strip
```